# Cannot see search by letter UI

Tags: filters

I have one User that can see this UI on the products list view which allows to filter by letter and other users cannot. 
Where do I configure this for all users?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is (at least, was, last time I looked) called the Rolodex, and it automatically appears when the list is sorted by a column that contains text (e.g. names, picklists, etc), and disappears for other types (e.g. dates, numbers, etc). There's nothing to enable or configure; the users just need to be aware of when it appears. Clicking on a different column to sort by that column will show or hide the Rolodex appropriately.